# what's wrong? j ? typeof j : var j = 9;

Tags: javascript

What's wrong with this code :

```
j ? typeof j : var j = 9;
```

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var

if j exists then I want to know the typeof , if j don't exist then assign 9 to j. The solution is below this but I was just wondering why the above code don't work.

```
if (j) { typeof j }else{var j = 9}
```

Comment: Operators don't accept statements as operands.

Comment: "I was just wondering why the above code don't work" Is "Because the spec says so" too terse?

Comment: Even if the syntax was legal, `var` statements are hoisted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for this:

```
var j = (j) ? typeof j : 9;
```

You can't use the `var` keyword in your ternary operation, you must use it before, with `j`
(`var j =`)

Explained:

```
j =  //assign the outcome of the conditional evaluation to 'j'
(j)  //if j exists (this is where you put your conditional expression)
?    //if it is true, i.e. j exists, it will be set to this value (typeof j)
:    //if it is false, i.e. j doesn't exist, it will be set to this value (9)
```

---

*RE your comments: I think this is the code for what you want to do:*

```
var j = (j) ? j : 9;
if (j !== 9) console.log(typeof j);
```

Comment: this is helpful maybe later I will understand but I can't get it to work like this : var j = (j !== "undefined") ? console.log(typeof j) : 9;
 // If J is undefined let me know what the type of it is else assign it to 9 . But when I run over it again I guess it wants to assign the whole thing "console.log" to j

Comment: I think I got it now:
if j exists then let j be j. If it don’t then j=9 EX#1 and console.log it else where, or get typeof else where. Don’t try to run code inside the expression with starting var j = cause it will assign the values in the expression to var j. If I am going to run code in the expression then make sure the item in question “j" exists 1st and take out var j= at the start then do the expression knowing now that j exists  Example#2 .

EXAMPLE#1
var j = {name:"Jhone", last:"Doe"} ;
var j = (j) ? j : 9;

EXAMPLE#2
(typeof j === “object”) ? do_something_true() : do_something_false();

Comment: ah ok , makes sense now. Thanks. If j does not exist give it the value of 9 then if we did not assign our value of 9 to j because j already exists somewhere then let me know what j is .

Answer (score 1):

The `var` reserved word is in another site:

Change this:

```
j ? typeof j : var j = 9;
```

To this:

```
var j = (j) ? typeof j  :  9;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an error, because you've given a statement as an operand to the ternary operator in your code. However, all operators expect operands being expressions.

What is the difference between expression and statement then? Expressions are evaluated to values, statements can't be evaluated to values. I.e. in your code `var j = 9` wouldn't return anything to the ternary operator.

Also, in a way, you're misusing the ternary operator, it returns a value, but you're not using it anywhere. In cases when utilizing the side effects only, you should use `if..else`, ternary operator is not purposed to produce side effects.

<sup>Correct use is well-explained in other answers here, so I won't do it again.</sup>